Where is the Charlatan Background in PHB 2024?
This source shows a bunch of character info for Charlatan, like Ideals, Flaws, etc.
[source is not an official D&D website, link removed because it has unauthorized copies of copyrighted rules text]
However, it says PHB is the source; yet, I have PHB 2024 and it doesn’t have this info for any backgrounds.
What’s confusing is that the basic rules on DND Beyond show Ideals/Flaws/etc., except that it’s limited to a few classes.
Where am I supposed to find this?
Also, I know I could make it up, but additionally this is important because of starting equipment like having a 2nd identity and the “tools of your favorite con”.

Welcome to the stack Alex, you might be in a position where a lot of content you find online doesn't fully match your new rulebook. The best thing to do is talk to your DM and work out how to best implement what you want to do, all the old stuff is meant to be compatible. It isn't always easy to make it so, but backgrounds are usually easy enough to adjust with a bit of understanding of both versions.

The Charlatan background can be found on page 179 of the 2024 PHB, but it seems you already know this. Your true questions seems to be "Why are there no flaws etc. for backgrounds in the 2024 PHB, if I can find them in these links"? I suggest you adjust the title.

Hi Alex, I think this is a legitimate question and your confusion will be shared as the rules base transitions. However, the site you linked to is a third party that AFAICT does not have an official relationship with D&D. One might call it a "pirate" site, and we don't promote those here, so I have removed that link.  Eddymage's answer includes legal links; the Charlatan material you reference is available for purchase but not for free.

@SeriousBri If you think network rules should be changed, or a site specific exception allowing us to vote on users rather than content, there are meta sites where that discussion can be had and approved by the community. Until that happens, please don’t discourage users for engaging with the site in a manner consistent with the site’s design and policies.

Reminder to everyone to be nice, and that the appropriate place to discuss site/network policies is in meta, not in the comments on a random question.

The description reported in the link refers to the 2014 PHB.
The Charlatan background described in the link is the one from the 2014 PHB.
The 2024 PHB, the one you possess, refers to the updated version of the 5th edition: the background mechanics are among the ones subject to some modifications with respect to the 2014 version. For example, comparing the two sets of free rules (2014, 2024), there are no more the tables for flaws, bonds, et cetera.

Comments are not for discussing whether you like the design decisions of the new edition; take it to chat, please.
